# creating python virtualenv keep showing error of syntax

Tags: python, virtualenv

After a successful installation of virtualenv on centos7

`pip install virtualenv`

while creating new virtualenv it keeps showing below mentioned error even if I am checking

`virtualenv --version`

This also shows the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .plugin.activators import ActivationSelector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/activators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import ComponentBuilder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/plugin/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from importlib_metadata import entry_points
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zipp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipp.py", line 153
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipp.py on line 154, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I tried to uninstall and re-install it again but so far no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Python 2.7 (which is end-of-life) with a version of Virtualenv that doesn't support Python 2.7.

In order of preference,

- stop using Python 2.7 and use Python 3.x (currently 3.8) instead
- or install an older version of Virtualenv (e.g. `pip install "virtualenv<20.0"`, or whatever major version of Virtualenv ends up working for you).

Comment: Definitely I need to upgrade soon.

Comment: I encounter with an issue after virtualenv creation which is I am not able to upgrade pip or any other package as it keeps showing error of ssl/https any idea about that ?

Comment: That's a different question (ask it separately with your commands and resulting error), and not knowing the error it's hard to help. Probably a network or proxy problem.

Comment: stackoverflow says i can't post next question within 90mins. waiting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821272/python3-8-virtualenv-pip-not-upgrading

Comment: virtualenv 20 seems to work with python 2.7 as of at least May 2020 and the changelog doesn't say anything about dropping support for python 2.7: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/changelog.html

Comment: @fields This was in March, things may have changed re Virtualenv since back then. However, Python 2 is still EOL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I get this similar error when running `workon <foo>`:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ workon foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from stevedore import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extension import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import _cache
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/_cache.py", line 31, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zipp
  File "/home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipp.py", line 153
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/xiaobai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipp.py on line 154, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
...
```

The error showing `python2.7/runpy.py` at the beginning but I expect to use python 3 in whole process.

Then I get same error when `source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh` too.

So I check the file and noticed it use python 2 based on result of `which python` command, which `/usr/bin/python` symlink to python2.7 in my system:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ grep -n which /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
50:    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
316:    typeset exe_path="$(command \which "$1" | (unset GREP_OPTIONS; command \grep -v "not found"))"
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

So simply edit this line to hard-coded path `/usr/bin/python3` (my python3 path), no more error either of `source` or `workon`:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sudo sed -i 's/VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \\which python)"/VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=\/usr\/bin\/python3/g' /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ grep -n which /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
316:    typeset exe_path="$(command \which "$1" | (unset GREP_OPTIONS; command \grep -v "not found"))"
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ grep -n python3 /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
50:    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ workon foo
(foo) xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

And of course, you can set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` environment variable if you want to use python 2 or 3 dynamically without edit this script.