# python3.8 virtualenv pip not upgrading

Tags: python, ssl, pip

On running following command

`pip install --upgrade pip`

it shows following error even I can't install any other packages as it says upgrade pip first.

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./environments/mjshare_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.3.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

if i run

`pip list`

i have following packages

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.3.1 
setuptools 42.0.2 
wheel      0.33.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with pip's version, but with ssl. The version of python you installed does not have the ssl module, which can occur if you compiled python without installing the libssl-dev headers. (Or the version you downloaded was made so).

Comment: Hi @Haytek so I have uninstalled the source code of python3 which I compiled and then did a clean install using `yum install python3` and now virtualenv are running like a charm. Thanks for helping me out. Cheers